# How to disable the ability to reset the password for the master DB instance user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I recently ran into a case where development was occurring on a client-provided account, and no IAM users were setup so everyone logged in through the root account (there's issues here, obviously).

An RDS instance running MySQL 5.6-compatible Aurora "Writer" instance had its master DB instance user password reset unexpectedly, causing many issues. Is there a way to disable this capability, which the acknowledgement that the data will be unrecoverable if access credentials have been lost?

Comment: When everyone is using root you can't stop anyone from doing everything. If they're IAM or federated users then you can look into permissions to prevent DB changes.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think theres a way of explcitly blocking changing the master password. You could use IAM to lock down modifying the RDS instances properties (RDS IAM permission ModifyInstance i think) - but that wont just prevent changing the password, but any modification of the instance.

Best option i can think of is to [create more than one `master level` account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/duplicate-master-user-mysql/). Essentially:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'new_master_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'new_master_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Either use this account as a backdoor in case you have this issue again, or give out accounts with these permissions instead of the actual master account? (obvs. you should really do least privilege/not share passwords/[insert your best practice here] - but im guessing you already know that :).